# How to capture error from the output of a command in batch script when the command fails?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I had a Jenkins job with multiple builds. Some steps were batch and some Powershell, most being batch. In various steps I run some `msbuild` commands, regular commands like `robocopy`, `zip`..., some `.bat`,`.ps1` scripts and some `.exe`' files.

I want to capture the errors when failed and save them to a file. I want every build step get executed irrespective of their failure. The Jenkins job should be successful.

For this I am force exiting 0 every build step. Before this I am trying capture errors to a file. With powershell it is easier using `-errorvariable` option or `try{}catch{}` block.

But in batch I am facing lot of troubles capturing errors from the command outputs, especially for some execuatbles and scripts only when the command fails.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: [`... 2>> error.log`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

Comment: If executables and scripts are well-done (they write errors to `stderr`) then you can always use `2>` instead of `>` to redirect (`>>` appends)

Comment: `>>logfile echo Last program exited with status %errorlevel%.`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti This is helpful. Thanks